# org-agenda-files not setting after update?

Tags: org-mode, init-file, org-agenda

I recently upgraded to emacs 25.1.1 and noticed my org setup wasn't working as usual. in my `init.el` I have:

```
(setq org-directory "~/Dropbox (Personal)/org")
(setq org-archive-location "~/Dropbox (Personal)/org/archive/%s_archive::")
(setq org-agenda-files (list "~/Dropbox (Personal)/org/journal"
                             "~/Dropbox (Personal)/org"
                             "~/Dropbox (Personal)/org/gmail-inbox.org.txt"))
```

when I view the agenda I'm not seeing any records from `/org/journal` being pulled in.

If I do `M-x describe-variable RET org-agenda-files`

I get

```
org-agenda-files is a variable defined in ‘org.el’.
Its value is
("/Users/kevzettler/Dropbox (Personal)/org/personal.org" "/Users/kevzettler/Dropbox (Personal)/org/plebland.org" "/Users/kevzettler/Dropbox (Personal)/org/tilt.org")

Original value was nil
```

Which looks like its only setting it to the what's available in `"~/Dropbox (Personal)/org"`

Comment: I can't reproduce this. Have you tried to stick for configuring     org-agenda-files with EITHER customize OR init.el?

Comment: is `~/Dropbox (Personal)/org/journal` a dir?

Comment: @YasushiShoji yes with many `.org` files in it

Comment: So it seems if I move the `org-agenda-files` file line to the end of my init.el line it works correctly. I"m not seeing anything else in init.el that would mess up the  sequence

Comment: If the code position in init.el is the case, it's hard to figure out without your init.el.  Is it possible to post your init.el somehow? Even better, can you make small init.el that can reproduce the same behavior?

Answer (score 0):

After install the package you should launch `M-x auto-package-update-now`

Remove your setting then `M-x package-install org-agenda-property`

Then follow the Dropbox information [Emacs Wiki dropbox](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DropBox)

It explain how

> (add-to-list 'auto-save-file-name-transforms '("\`.*/Dropbox/.*" "/tmp/" t))
>
> (add-to-list 'backup-directory-alist '("\`.*/Dropbox/.*" . "/tmp/"))